# Android Studio 3.2 RC2 endless indexing

Tags: android, android-studio

Got a problem with newly updated Android Studio 3.2 RC2, it doing endless indexing at startup. Also, I cannot stop this process. Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason was my anti-virus software. Solved.